# A puzzle based purely on probability

Tags: probability

I have converted an algorithmic problem of mine into a probability game (I'm truly grateful for any solutions)...

...

You are blindfolded.

There are 436 barrels in a garden, each barrel contains a bunch of silver coins.

6 of those barrels contain golden coins as well as silver coins.

If you put your hand into a barrel containing golden coins, there is only a 70% chance that you will actually take out a golden coin.

Probability-wise what is the best procedure to find the gold coin in the least amount of "Checks".

If you pick a gold coin out of the barrel a third party will shout "YOU WIN!" (since you can't actually know whether you picked a gold or silver coin, being blindfolded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how you can do much better than just trying every barrel. So if the barrels are labeled 1,2,...,436, then start by trying barrel 1, then 2,..., up to 436. Then start over. The chance of not getting a gold coin in such a run is $0.3^6$, which means the probability of success follows a geometric random variable with probability $p=0.7$. In other words, the chance of not getting the gold coin on the first run is $0.3^6=0.0000729$, meaning you'll need around 1 run to get your coin, 2 if you're ridiculously unlucky, 3 if hell freezes over.